# Powershell Get-ChildItem fails with 'Access is denied' as a remote call

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to query the files on the remote machine using the following syntax, it fails with access is denied / permission denied. Am I missing something,

The permissions on the target are given with full control and to all folder, subfolders and files. Permissions are given at Y: volume level.

```
Get-ChildItem \\serverA\Y$\folderA\

Get-ChildItem : Access is denied
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem \\serverA\Y$\folderA\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\serverA...\:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\serverA\Y$\folderA\' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem \\serverA\Y$\folderA\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\serverA...\:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: Did you check both the permissions on the share and the permissions at the filer/folder level?

Comment: As @squillman points out, there are two sets of permissions.  Microsoft simplified the sharing settings a long time ago and treated them as one thing when they are not.

Comment: I’m trying to access a non shared remote path, where Y is drive letter. All the permissions are given at security level of the drive with all folders/sub folders/files at all child levels.

Comment: I've seen assertions, like one here, indicating that only members of the local admin group can access default $<drive-letter> shares. they are by definition "Administrative shares". Perhaps try creating your own hidden share like `drive_c$`. http://woshub.com/enable-remote-access-to-admin-shares-in-workgroup/

Comment: In order to diagnose this I would expect the output of something like `dir \\serverA\Y$\folderA\` and have it list files.

Comment: I was able to access the path when the account is added to local admin group, that answers why I'm not able to access Y$ location. 
btw, I have tried converting the same to network share and able to access that with permissions granted on share and security props without needing to be part of local admin group. 
@FrankThomas Thank you for that pointer.

Comment: If it's available on the network, it's a shared remote path.  `Y$` is an administrative share, so the account you use to access the shared resource needs to have admin access on the remote machine.